# How to increase number of mappers in Mahout MatrixMultiplicationJob?

Tags: hadoop, matrix, mapreduce, mahout, multiplication

I am using Mahout 0.7's `MatrixMultiplicationJob` for multiplying a large matrix. But it always uses 1 map task which makes it slow. its probably due to the `InputSplit` which forces the number of mappers to be 1.

Is there a way I can efficiently multiply matrices in Hadoop / Mahout or change the number of mappers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, it is Hadoop that decides how many mappers to use. Generally it will use one mapper per HDFS block (typically 64 or 128MB). If your data is smaller than that, it's too small to bother with more than 1 mapper.

You can encourage it to use more anyway by setting `mapred.max.split.size` to something smaller than 64MB (remember the value is set in bytes, not MB). But, are you sure you want to? It is much more common to need more reducers, not mappers, since Hadoop will never use more than 1 unless you (or your job) tells it to.

Also know that Hadoop will not be able to use more than one mapper on a single *compressed* file. So if your input is one huge compressed file, it will only ever use 1 mapper on that file. You can however split it up yourself into many smaller compressed files.

Comment: Hi, I realized that hadoop wont use more than one mapper on a single file. I converted it to N files and it ran with N mappers.

Comment: I have another issue though. I have a matrix A (65k*130k) which is sparse. I have computed transpose(A) using mahout's transposeJob. I want to multiple the transpose by itself, so as to get A*At. Whenever I run multiplication on this transpose, it generates a hell lot of more FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN. And after a while, I start getting Out of Disk Space on mappers and the tasks start failing. While it writes around 160GB for A, it writes 500GB+ for At even at 60% completion. What might be happening?

Comment: It will use multiple mappers on one file, if it's big enough and it is not compressed. I dont know the transpose job, it may just not be optimized. I thought it was already computing At * A? Don't know.

Comment: Ya, Mahout computes At*A. But what I want is A*At, hence I am doing the transpose first and then multiplying, so I can get A*At. I have tried using 1 sequence file but too slow. I tried breaking it into multiple seq files but everytime the data written is too much and leads to timeouts n disk space errors.

Comment: OK, sounds fine. I have no idea why it would write so much intermediate data. I don't know if it's optimized for sparse data.

Answer (score 0):

had you tried to specify number of mappers via command line with `-Dmapred.map.tasks=N` option? I hadn't tried it, but it should work. If it won't work, then try to set this parameter in the `MAHOUT_OPTS` environment variable...

Comment: -Dmapred.map.tasks=N does not work for mahout matrixmult.  I have not tried the MAHOUT_OPTS.